# Finding a term in a list

Tags: python

I have the following code to find the keywords in a user's profile:

```
    profile_text = self.text.lower()
    term_string = ''
    TERMS = ['spring',  'java', 'angular', 'elastic', 'css']
    for term in TERMS:
        if term in profile_text: term_string += term.strip() + ', '
    return term_string.strip(' ,')
```

This will return something like:

```
"spring, angular, css"
```

However, it will also return "java" if the user has a word such as "javascript". What would be a good pattern to prevent that?

Comment: Guess would help to disclose what `profile_text` is

Comment: I believe there are two ways of doing this: one is [using regexes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm), the other is putting spaces before and after the words you want to match so that it will only match spaced words:

`TERMS = ['spring ',  'java ', 'angular ', 'elastic ', 'css ']`

Comment: An example of profile_text?

Comment: LTKills -- yes, I tried the space approach first but it seemed to be quite weak, for example, someone could have something like `"Experienced in java, python, and sql."` and it wouldn't pick up any of those terms because of the punctuation after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regular expressions.

You could do something like:

```
import re

TERMS = ['spring',  'java', 'angular', 'elastic', 'css']
matched_terms = []
for term in TERMS:
    if re.search(r'\b{}\b'.format(term), profile_text, re.M):
        matched_terms.append(term)
return ', '.join(matched_terms)
```

Comment: Add `(?i)` to the beginning of the regex, or it won't match "Spring" or "Java"

Comment: I actually assumed he wanted it case sensitive...but if he wants it case insensitive then he should just add the `re.I` flag....the flags argument then would become `re.M | re.I`.